# Duplicate MessageConverters in RestTemplateBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-web

I'm using `spring-boot` with `spring-web` and `jackson`.

Problem: when a `RestTemplate` is initialized automatically by spring, the constructor receives some duplicate `MessageConverters`:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@6a1b4854,
org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@2d5b549b, 
org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@6a175162, 
org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter@7641c4e7, 
org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter@650a0b50, 
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter@55e3b64d, 
org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@52f71d2, 
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@f3c27e9, 
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7d31fb6c, 
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter@701c413, 
org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter@48543f11
```

You see, there are 3 duplicates:

```
StringHttpMessageConverter
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter
```

As I don't initialize any message converters myself: why does the application context contain duplicate converters at all, that are then added to the resttemplate?

Especially: doesn't this confuse the (de)serializing if some converters occur duplicate (but with different configuration)?

For example: the `ObjectMapper` of the first `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` contains more `registeredModuleTypes` `[Jdk8Module, JavaTimeModule, ParamterNamesModule, JsonComponentModule, GeoModule]` than the 2nd one (that only contains: `[Jdk8Module, JavaTimeModule]`).

Does that make sense?

It's instantiated via `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.restTemplateBuilder()`, there all the duplicate `MessageConverters` are already present.

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint at the constructor and post the entire call-stack? I want to see from where it gets instantiated.

Comment: It comes from `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.restTemplateBuilder()`. So it just injects any `HttpMessageConverters` found on classpath. The question is why there might be duplicates?

Comment: Well, that's all what I was able to get.

Comment: Added explanation on how Spring chooses the `HttpMessageConverter`. See at bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is here, at `HttpMessageConverters`

```
public HttpMessageConverters(boolean addDefaultConverters,
        Collection<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> combined = getCombinedConverters(converters,
            addDefaultConverters ? getDefaultConverters() : Collections.emptyList());
    combined = postProcessConverters(combined);
    this.converters = Collections.unmodifiableList(combined);
}
```

Specifically, this line (formatted)

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> combined = 
       getCombinedConverters(
           converters, 
           addDefaultConverters 
               ? getDefaultConverters() 
               : Collections.emptyList());
```

The `converters` collection contains the scanned `HttpMessageConverter`(s).
Based on the environment.

[image]

That list is then joined with a *default* one provided by `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

[image]

```
public class WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements ApplicationContextAware, ServletContextAware {
    private static final boolean romePresent;
    private static final boolean jaxb2Present;
    private static final boolean jackson2Present;
    private static final boolean jackson2XmlPresent;
    private static final boolean jackson2SmilePresent;
    private static final boolean jackson2CborPresent;
    private static final boolean gsonPresent;
    private static final boolean jsonbPresent;
    ...
```

Infact the documentations for `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` states

> This class registers ...
>   ... a range of `HttpMessageConverters` depending on the third-party libraries available on the classpath.

The scanned `HttpMessageConverter`(s) are found and instantiated via `HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration`, whose documentation is

> Auto-configuration for `HttpMessageConverters`.

That class exposes by itself a `StringHttpMessageConverter`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(
            this.properties.getCharset());
    converter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
    return converter;
}
```

Than, it imports Jackson or Gson auto-configurations

```
@Import({ 
    JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.class
    GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.class,
    JsonbHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.class 
})
```

And that's how those environment-based ones are "summed" to the pre-defined ones.

---

Spring doesn't get confused by duplicates because it just takes the first which is compatible.
See how an `HttpMessageConverter` is choosed

[image]

You can see it is just a simple for loop, and each convert is asked to say "can I do this?" via the `canWrite` method

[image]

The first valid is picked.

Comment: tyvm for your detailed insight!

Comment: @membersound oh no problem. It was fun. If you need other clarifications let me know.